How I can to import my automation account job schedule in Terraform?
How can I import my schedule job of my runbook of my automation account to manage it from Terraform?
We have created it from outside our IaC and now we need it to be managed from Terraform so that everything is integrated correctly.
I have been running the following. But none of these commands work:
terraform import 'module.automation_account_powershell["eastus"].azurerm_automation_job_schedule.atm' /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/jobSchedules/filesharepvc
terraform import 'module.automation_account_powershell["eastus"].azurerm_automation_job_schedule.atm' /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/schedules/filesharepvc
terraform import 'module.automation_account_powershell["eastus"].azurerm_automation_job_schedule.atm' /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/jobSchedules/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/schedules/filesharepvc
Is it possible to import this type of resource? If import is possible how can I import my job schedule?

What does "none of them work" means? Also, please format your question so it's more readable.

Sorry, I wanted to say that none of the commands worked

Can you share the errors you got?

for job shedules in general we dont specifies name where as youre calling job shedules using names while importing which is not possible. we may need job shedule id info to import that resource into the state file follow:  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/examples/automation-account/main.tf

may i know what exactly you're trying to import schedule or job schedule? @Dielam

I am trying to import the job schedule.
Like this resource: resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule"

I try to import the job schedule, because this part was done manually by another team. This kind of resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule".

I was finally able to import my resource.
The problem was the version of azurerm I was using.
I was using a version much older than the latest one (3.95.0) and the way to import the resource was different.
The correct command for me was the following:

terraform import
'module.automation_account_powershell["eastus"].azurerm_automation_job_schedule.atm'
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/jobSchedules/e66a490b-6245-4530-a03f-904bfd293r78



Import my automation account job schedule in Terraform

The error you're facing is because of the way you providing the import command. To import the job schedule we need to specify the id of job schedule rather than the name mentioned.
As per the GITHUB link the name of job schedule was not directly specified which means in order to achieve this requirement we need ID.
I tried a terraform configuration which mention the same and I was able to achieve the requirement.
main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "automation_account_powershell" {
  source = "./modules/automation_account_powershell"
  locations = {
    "eastus" = {
      resource_group_name     = "rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus"
      automation_account_name = "aa-eastus-pro"
      runbook_name            = "Get-AzureVMTutorial"
      schedule_name           = "dailySchedule"
    }
  }
}

output "job_schedule_ids" {
  value = module.automation_account_powershell.job_schedule_ids
}

module/automation_account_powershell/main.tf:
variable "locations" {
  type = map(object({
    resource_group_name     = string
    automation_account_name = string
    runbook_name            = string
    schedule_name           = string
  }))
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_automation_account" "automation" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name                = each.value.automation_account_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  sku_name            = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "runbook" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name                    = each.value.runbook_name
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.automation[each.key].name
  log_verbose             = true
  log_progress            = true
  runbook_type            = "PowerShellWorkflow"

  publish_content_link {
    uri            = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/c4935ffb69246a6058eb24f54640f53f69d3ac9f/101-automation-runbook-getvms/Runbooks/Get-AzureVMTutorial.ps1"
    version        = "1.0.0"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_automation_schedule" "schedule" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name                    = each.value.schedule_name
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.automation[each.key].name
  frequency               = "Day"
  interval                = 1
  timezone                = "UTC"
  start_time              = "2024-07-10T16:20:35Z"  
}

resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule" "job_schedule" {
  for_each = var.locations
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.automation[each.key].name
  schedule_name           = azurerm_automation_schedule.schedule[each.key].name
  runbook_name            = azurerm_automation_runbook.runbook[each.key].name
}

output "job_schedule_ids" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_automation_job_schedule.job_schedule : k => v.id }
}

Beforeimporting try fetch this id from the resources in the portal and I tried to implement the same to use the terraform to import.

Now I tried to import job schedules to the configuration info to the state file.
terraform import 'module.automation_account_powershell.azurerm_automation_job_schedule.job_schedule["eastus"]' "/subscriptions/98bccad1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-78dfd797ff89/resourceGroups/rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/schedules/dailySchedule|/subscriptions/98bccad1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-78dfd797ff89/resourceGroups/rg-phoenix2cloud-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/runbooks/Get-AzureVMTutorial"



Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_job_schedule
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_schedule
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_runbook

Thank you very much for the help and information.
I have tried as you told me but it returns the following errors:
Error: parsing "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/schedules/dailySchedule|/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/runbooks/monitor": parsing segment "staticJobSchedules": parsing the JobSchedule ID: the segment at position 8 didn't match

The command I tried was: terraform import 'module.automation_account_powershell["eastus"].azurerm_automation_job_schedule.atm' '/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/schedules/dailySchedule|/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/aa-eastus-pro/runbooks/monitor'
